# Flag decline reasons are now harder to read than before; please increase their contrast ratio

Tags: feature-request, declined-flags, flag-history, accessibility

It seems like the color for flag decline reasons was changed recently to a lighter shade of red, as part of the global CSS refactor that's been going on for months now.

I find the text of flag decline reasons a little harder to read, as a result:

> [image: Lighter decline reason text]

While the contrast ratio of the text, at 5.74:1, [is compliant with WCAG 2 Level AA](https://userway.org/contrast/c02d2e/ffffff), the text of these decline reasons is a bit *smaller* than normal text, and so it's a bit difficult to read. It would be very nice if that was compliant with Level AAA, which has a minimum requirement of 7:1, so it's much easier to read.

Can this text please be made darker and compliant with the Level AAA standard?

Comment: This is correct. I've also just tested the text color on [WebAIM: Contrast Checker](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) for flag decline reasons with dark mode enabled. The contrast ratio is 2.39:1, which isn't compliant with WCAG AA or AAA for text (#C02D2E) on a dark background (#2D2D2D).